# Formula to Decrease Text/Number combination by 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any suggestions on if you can create a formula for lowering a number within text by one?

So for example, I work in creating policies.  I’m creating a merge template in Word and there’s a blank for this year’s policy number and the previous year’s policy number.  The first year’s policy number is for example POL123456, the next year is POL123456-01, the next year is POL123456-02.

If the policy number is in Cell A2 as:  POL123456-02 is there a way to populate it in Cell B2 as POL123456-01, decreasing the last digit by 1?

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string to remove the last two characters then concatenate the TEXT() of those last two minus 1, formatting them as `"00"` to make sure it is two digits:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2) & TEXT(RIGHT(A2,2)-1,"00")
```

[image]